# Cannot access services on OpenVPN Bridge

Tags: routes, tap, openvpn

Currently I can enable the OpenVPN with tap and bridge. The Client connects and can access the network(192.168.6.X) and can also access the internet via 192.168.6.1. The OpenVPN server ip is 192.168.6.114.

The problem is when I enable OpenVPN all of the services running on the OpenVPN server cannot be accessed.

If i comment out 'route add default gw $eth_gateway $br'
I can acess my services but clients connect but cannot access anything on the network.

If i enable that line client can access everything but cannot access services on the server

here is a route before and after

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.6.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         192.168.6.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
default         192.168.6.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth1
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.6.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.6.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eth1
root@VPS:/etc/openvpn# service openvpn stop
root@VPS:/etc/openvpn# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.6.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         192.168.6.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth1
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.6.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.6.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eth1
```

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/openvpn/bridge-conf
#################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
#################################

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
    iptables -A INPUT -i $t -j ACCEPT
done

iptables -A INPUT -i $br -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $br -j ACCEPT

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
ip link set $br address $eth_mac
route add default gw $eth_gateway $br
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, the problem may be NAT loopback issue. Weird thing is if I stop the OpenVPN service the NAT Loopback does not happen and works properly.

Does Not Work
192.168.6.23(port 80) => mydns.com => ExternalIPRouter => NAT(Port80) => 192.168.6.114

Does Work
(External IP) => mydns.com => ExternalIPRouter => NAT(Port80) => 192.168.6.114

Does Work
192.168.6.23(Local HOST file mydns.com = 192.168.6.114) => 192.168.6.114(port 80)